# Chrome extension sign in also signs in Rails+Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, devise

### Context:

I have a chrome extension that pops-up when users connect to a given site (eg: https://www.site-triggering-extension.com)

This extension communicates with a Rails app (that uses Devise) deployed on Heroku (https://www.my-app.com). The basic user flow is :

- Users sign-up on the Rails app to create an account
- Then they can log-in on the chrome extension and use it
- My Rails app has an API that allows the chrome extension to send some usage logs that I store.

To authenticate my users on the chrome extension, I set up an authentication_token exchange between the extension & the Rails app.

### Problem :

**Users logged-in on the chrome extension are not logged in on the Rails app**.
And the Rails app allows them to access a dashboard with their logs, modify their account infos, etc.

=> Having to enter your login+password on both the chrome extension AND the Rails app seems unnecessary and adds friction to the whole experience.

**How could I set up my system so that logging-in on the chrome extension also logs-in the user on my Rails app ?**

### What I tried :

I am probably completely in the wrong direction here but still I wanted to describe what I looked at :

- My extension logs the user in by make a call to the `/api/sign_in` route that sends back the authentication token.
- I realized that the response from Rails has a `Set-Cookie` header with `_my_app_session` cookie in it. This looks like the type of cookie Rails+Devise could use to consider the user as logged in. However, this cookie is stored (in the DevTools - Application pannel) under `http://www.site-triggering-extension.com` as the API call originated from this site.
- When I open a tab and load my Rails app, the cookie does not seem to be used by the Rails app site (https://www.my-app.com).

I have no idea how to tackle this issue. Help would be highly appreciated !